# is there any way to check an empty nosql document property object without a function?

Tags: javascript, nosql

I have a noSQL document with an empty object:

```
{
    property: {}
}
```

And in my node js backend i want to check that is empty or not, I know that it´s possible to implement a function that checks object keys and says if it has no keys but i want implement (in backend) something like:

```
 if (property === {}) do something;
```

Is there any elegant solution without implementing a exclusive function for this purpose?

Comment: Nope, standard javascript doesn't have means for checking if an object is empty. You have to write a function or, better, use an already written one. Here is [an example of one in underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty).

Comment: :( .... Thank you so much!!!! :):)

Answer (score 0):

you can use lodash

```js
var d = {
    property: {}
}

console.log(
    _.isEqual(d.property, {})
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```